# How to define an array-property as comma separated?

Tags: arrays, json, csv, openapi

How can I define an [`array`](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/data-models/data-types/#array) object property, that contains several items in a `comma separated` string in openapi-v3?

I want to validate a request body (not query parameter!) like this:

```
{
    "friends": "Ann,Bob"
}
```

I am dreaming of an openApi v3 schema definition like this one:

```
"friends": {
    "type": "array",
    "items": {
        "type": "string",
        "enum": [
          "Ann",
          "Bob",
          "Charlie"
        ]
    },
    "commaSeparation": ",", // does not exist
}
```

Is there a officially supported way to describe such string contents? If not: What could be a workaround, that still precisely defines and validates those texts?

Comment: Consider also asking this in the OpenAPI Specification repository: https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/issues

Answer (score 3):

No, there is not. Unfortunately to the parser `friends` is and will always be a string.

You could add a pattern regex to enforce the contents, something like:

```json
"friends": {
    "type": "string",
    "pattern": "[Ann|Bob|Charlie],+" // some regex that enforces the allowed tokens and a trailing comma
}
```

If you want a real array, then you need to use an array type.

Comment: Thanks for Your helpful answer. The regex however seems to work: https://regexr.com/5nd8g